# Single sign-on system for multiple codeigniter webapps?

Tags: single-sign-on, codeigniter-3

I have at least 6 or 7 codeigniter 3.x web apps to handle my company operations. I would like to incorporate it as an ERP, so that user can have only one login and use required apps based on the permissions given.

Right now i have different login windows and sessions for different apps.

Any suggestions to do this?
is it possible to retain the session in multiple codeigniter apps?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an OpenID connect server (OIDC), similar to what you see in websites which have login with facebook or Google features.

You can look to host https://github.com/identityserver which I am using or any other you find easier. These servers are meant to be independent of Client's (your apps) platform and works off of HTTP requests.

How it works:

1. User opens one of your app.
2. The app shows login screen that redirects to the OIDC server.
3. The user logins in the server, creates session/cookie and it redirects back to the app with necessary auth tokens.
4. User opens another one of your apps.
5. It redirects to OIDC server, server already has active session, and return back to the app with required apps without need to login.

This is just basic way, how it works, of course you can tweak it make it work as you need.